# show/hide drop down menu on hover using css

Tags: html, css

So I've got the following code and I'm basically trying to display extra links to click on once you hover over the "My Account" option.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="wrapper">
<div id ="banner"><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="269px" ImageUrl="~/" Width="100%" /></div>
             <div id ="navigation">
                 <ul id="nav">
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Security/Default.aspx">Home</asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">Using the System</asp:HyperLink></li>                   
                     <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server">My Account</asp:HyperLink>
                         <ul id ="test">
                               <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a> </li>
                         </ul>
                         <li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #navigation {
    height: 45px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);
}

#nav li{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul li:hover #test{
    visibility:visible;
}
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;  
}
#test ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:125px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be doing anything, any ideas on what to alter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #navigation {
    height: 45px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #c2bcb5, #ffffff);
}

#nav li{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav li:hover #test{
    display:block;
}
#nav ul {
    display: none; /*  this property must be changed on hover  */
    list-style: none;  
}
#test ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:125px;

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9f3s4z5/

You have set display property to none, for #nav ul, but you have just changed visibility on hover. Also, right selector is: #nav li:hover #test, without ul, because #nav is actually ul id. (and, #test ul and #nav ul should css's shouldn't be separated, if i am right, it is same element?)

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of targeting the list element with "My Account" and use the :hover selector. One possible solution would be to use the nth-child selector like this:

```
#test ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:125px;
    /*  Changed display instead of visibility so test ul doesn't take up space on the page */
    display: none;
}

/* When user hovers over the 3rd li element, the css code for the ul with the id test takes effect */
li:nth-child(3):hover ul#test {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ok so i can see the hyperlink "hyperlink 2.1" in design view (without the display:none property for #nav ul) but running the website ommits this option.

Comment: If you're running internet explorer, nth-child selectors only work on versions 9+.

Comment: I'm using chrome(Version 38.0.2125.111 m). Just ran the code with IE and it seems to be working...hmmm wonder why chrome is blocking it

Comment: Might be user user agent stylesheet. The other two answers work fine so hopefully you can get it working! Good luck (=.

Comment: thank you, not sure what it was but it seems to be working now - just left it alone for a while ran it again and it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Below is code generated by cutting your code down to just the basics -- you add the extra bits and pieces later.

I believe this css has the behavior you are looking for.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Using the System</li>
        <li>My Account
            <ul id="test">
                <li>Hyperlink 2.1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```